# Notification for edited question

Tags: feature-request, editing, answers

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that when a question is edited, no notification is sent to who has answered before that.

Since the edit can change the answer needed, shouldn't be implemented this feature, in a way such the one who answered can update his informations?

Comment: +1 .. Good idea

Comment: @Kortuk that was a sort of demostration? I've received the message, but not the balloon is it normal?

Answer (score 5):

I like this idea.  I sometimes give a partial answer and ask for more clarification.  It would be nice to know when that happens.  Currently I only catch it if the OP specifically writes a comment to me or the questions pops near the top of the list due to the recent activity.  It would be nice to get a deliberate notification.

Comment: sorry.......OP?

Comment: @clabacchio, stands for original poster. He means he is only pinged if the user targets him in a comment.

Comment: yes, I had understood the idea, but not the acronym...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough issue because the last thing I want is a notification when someone fixed a typo in their question.

Generally most of the edits I see to questions were either minor typo corrections or were brought on by a series of comments that occurred before any answer was written. In cases that someone did answer, it usually seems pretty clear to me that they shouldn't have answered until there was more clarification.

Now, there are cases that I have seen an edit to a question that does not fall into the circumstances I mentioned before and it would be very nice if there was an alert of the change. I also think these changes are the ones that are worthy of being bumped to the top of the front page. People before have recommended having some option to select if the edit is minor or major. If it is ever determined to have something like this added then I would be in full support of alerts when a major edit is made. But until then I think there would be too many annoying alerts for minor edits that it just isn't worth the feature.

Comment: And an automatic check, that occurs only when new content is added, or a minimum number of characters? It should be quite easy to implement, just checking the body length and\or number of paragraphs...because I'm afraid that a manual control is easy to forget...

Comment: Another way for what you are saying, is a sort of tag in the edit explanation, with the keyword minor-major required...

Comment: @clabacchio agreed with everything you said. I was trying to avoid getting into that part of the discussion and just be more general saying that if something like that where to happen then I would support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

An edit that completely changes the question should only happen if there is an issue with the question that requires a complete correction. At this point people should not have been writing answers to an unanswerable question anyway.

Comment: But can happen that an edit adds some requirements that invalidate the previous answers: budget limits, precision, equipment, or so on...

Comment: @clabacchio, hopefully the user notes if anything in an answer is no longer valid. I see the validity in this, but only for some things. We will see how users vote.

Comment: I admit that it's not ALWAYS useful, but a notification, especially in a not so busy site like this, in my opinion is not so harmful, and for the cases in which can help, I think it's worth...but I respect your opinion (of moderator :D)...but if i disagree i have to vote down right?

Comment: @clabacchio, on this the fact that I am a moderator just makes me another user whom spends more time talking to others about these things, your vote down is just as deserved as if I was not a moderator and you disagreed.

Comment: Ahaha it was just a joke :) but I get the point, thank you!

Comment: It's not just about large changes to the question.  I want to know about small changes, perhaps clarifications I even asked for.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, Yes, at first I was hesitant, but I find myself liking the idea. Although I already log in having at least 4 notifications every single time.

Comment: @Kortuk Maybe I'm a too young user, but by now I don't find annoying the notifications, especially when i can skip them from the menu...

Comment: @clabacchio I have received about 20 notification in the last 24 hours. As of now I don't find them annoying because all of the notifications I get are relevant to what I want to see, but if it would be very annoying to be getting notification on every little edit that someone made to a question I answered.

Comment: @Kellenjb, maybe excluding tag edits.